# How can I appeal a rejection of a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[One of my recent suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/144401), for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274691/how-to-handle-different-user-types-by-using-groups), was rejected.  I also went ahead and answered the question and my answer was accepted by the user.

I think the fact my answer was accepted demonstrates that I understood the question, and I believe that my edits would have given the question more attention in general from other users with the potential to answer the question.  I'm not terribly concerned about rep, I'm just curious about how to proceed in a case like this.  Should I resubmit the suggested edits?  Is there some sort of appeal process?  Since the answer is accepted should I even bother?

Comment: How is `How can I define this SQL Schema?` more specific than `How to handle different user types by using groups?`? Your modified title provides absolutely no details as to the content of the question that the tags don't already identify.

Comment: You're right, the tags do address that to some level.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no mechanism to appeal rejected edits.

Looks like you have removed some tags, which may be why the edit was rejected.

You can always edit the question *again* and supply more details in the reason (and be a little more judicial in your edits).

Comment: Alright.  I disagree with the decision and think my edit actually helps the user.  Is there any course forward or does it just stand until I have the appropriate rep?

Comment: @BertEvans - Two other users with appropriate rep thought your edit was not good. There is no mechanism to appeal these decisions. I suggest you edit _again_, but more prudently.

Comment: @BertEvans: There is, of course, the possibility that you are wrong ;)

Comment: Heh, absolutely!

Comment: I just made changes to a code snippet that wouldn't compile as is.  The changes were minor, but had to be applied throughout the code.  Four reviewers weighed in:  one approved the edit, two rejected it for changing too much, and one for being too minor a change.

Comment: @NSNoob - I would have rejected that too. The formatting change is minimal and not particularly helpful (I don't really care about the last brace, the code in general is already readable and formatted correctly). Making "Ans at" a link and not even fixing the wording and explaining what that means? This was a bad edit.

Answer (score 6):

You can bring it up in the site's chat, e.g., "Anything wrong with my suggested edit here?".

This is what I did when my edit on Ask Different got rejected. A local high-rep user (actually, a mod) agreed with the edit, and implemented it himself. No +2 for me, but that wasn't the point of editing.

Comment: How can you find a site's chat? chat.stackexchange.com doesn't look to have site-specific rooms.

Answer (score 4):

I was hit by this issue as well: [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/935214) was approved by two editors, and rejected by others. Those who rejected it had no experience whatsoever with the subject matter (MongoDB).

It is highly frustrating that people with experience in one domain, can wield their power in areas they are not competent in. If society worked that way, then Albert Einstein would be allowed to perform brain surgery.

Please,

1. do implement a mechanism to challenge rejected edits
2. or, disallow editors from accepting/rejecting an edit if they don't have experience with any of the tags of the question

Comment: You should have provided a new answer. The fact that the answer was accepted doesn't matter. If there's new information that renders an old answer obsolete then that information should be in a new answer.

Comment: I provided a comment, because I'm realistic that new answers with zero votes most likely won't be read when existing answers have 6 votes, and are accepted.

Comment: In that case comment rather than edit the answer.

Comment: *rolleyes* I guess I'll just have to give up.

Comment: I would also suggest, that canned response should not be allowed as a rejection reasons.

Comment: As if to prove a point, I tried to edit this answer to add the feature-request tag, so your ideas would be shown to the developers. My edit was rejected because it 'did not make the answer easier to find' and it was 'superfluous to need'. But it _did_ make the answer easier to find...

Comment: @DanDascalescu It happened to me also.In my opinion.If i am the reviewer if i don't have knowledge of that language i will neither accept nor reject. I will leave it for other reviewer. I will approve for cosmetic and grammatical edits only (if it is not my language/technology). But all reviewer does not thinks like me and they will not spend time on understanding that edit, they have only one snippet running in their mind `if(I_Can't_Understand){ reject }`

Answer (score 3):

In the section **I disagree with the reasons why my edit was rejected. What can I do?** in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) very well written and complete answer states the following:

- Ask for clarification about why your edit was rejected in the site's chat.
- Do not simply suggest the edit again, or it will likely be rejected again.
- If the edit was to address a legitimate policy concern, flag the post for moderator attention.