# Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, notifications, rejected-edits

> **Update, April 2014:** I fully support [Shog9's proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor#137334) of adding the message where it belongs—in the actual editing form. This is less intrusive than displaying it as a notification, but it serves the same purpose. Can has?

---

### Background

When you suggest an edit, the outcome of whether it was approved or rejected is buried deep within your profile. You have to navigate to *Profile » Activity » Suggestions* to find a list of your recent edits, but even those do not say anything about the outcome:

[image]

waffles♦ introduced this [to "facilitate learning"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107930/159624), but what can I learn from this page? I have to manually click through the edits to see whether they were rejected or not. This is  time-consuming or inefficient at best. There's also **no learning involved** at all, since there is **no active feedback**.

---

### Feature request #1

If an edit was rejected, there should be a notification message displayed, linking to the page of the suggested edit (which states the reject reason).

[image]

This kind of feedback would improve the editing behavior, since otherwise, inappropriate suggestions might just continue.

---

### Feature request #2

If the above is too intrusive, the messages in the profile's *Activity* section should be clearer, for example like this (compare against the first screenshot in the question):

> [image]

This is similar to: [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history)

---

Here's some more explanation:

Let's assume the case of a user suggesting lots of edits that are in some way harmful. Maybe they were too minor, like only changing keyboard shortcuts to use `kbd` markup instead of boldface.

Yes, we've already had this on Super User. Since it only takes one user to approve / reject there, some of these edits might even have been wrongfully accepted, others  rejected. While this is a problem of its own, the user *suggesting* these edits will have a hard time even getting any kind of feedback.

They would *never* see the rejection messages because they're buried somewhere, unless they critically checked each suggestion in their profile. I doubt anybody would do this. Even more so, they might only look at their steadily climbing reputation, not really noticing a rejected edit.

Another case is users *learning* how to edit. How are we [going to guide them](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4418/editing-privileges-suspended-reactivated-at-2k-rep#comment11086_4418) if they're not told what they did wrong? They will just continue suggesting edits until somebody actually pings them in chat or comments somewhere.

Here's an [example](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days-what-did-i-do-wrong) of a user who was completely unaware that he could see feedback somewhere in a dark corner of his profile, until he was banned from editing because he'd repeated the same mistake over and over.

Comment: ... especially given the time span between suggesting and having it accepted. On smaller sites than SO, this can be a while. Even on SU, I have seen suggested edits for 1+ hours in the queue.

Comment: I'm not sure *how* related this is, but I'd also be [keen to get feedback](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58448/my-suggested-edit-votes-that-got-overruled) on which of my suggested edit votes were overruled (I guess this is a unique problem for Stack Overflow as all(?) the other sites only require 1 vote, where as SO requires 2). Feedback on both sides lets a) the reviewers how to vote correctly, and b) the editors how to edit correctly.

Comment: @DanielBeck Last time I checked there was one sitting for 13 hours waiting to be accepted or rejected.

Comment: If this gets implemented, the same needs to be done for declined flags.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Now that you say it, that actually make sense and add to some consistency.

Comment: Do we already have some sort of protection against repeated identical suggested edits? That's the one thing I fear, users will try to do their same edits repeatedly until they get accepted, and then they're in. So if this were introduced, making everybody immediately aware of rejected edits (and possibly flags as suggested by @BoltClock'saUnicorn), we probably should get some sort of "suggested edit spam filter".

Comment: @Daniel: Well, they're suggested edit still exists, just declined. Maybe they could set it up so that new suggested edit != old suggested edit. There's not really a *great* way of countering this because they could just change a couple spaces that were not changed before to fool it, and we don't want to use substantial difference criterion because it could potentially forbid them from submitting a further suggested edit.

Comment: [Maximum number of edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136737) and [Tag editing limits - Give us a chance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136915) seem to indicate that this would be a useful feature

Comment: Could you mock up "Your edits on [topic] and three others were reviewed, click here to learn more", "Your edit on [topic] was approved, click here to learn more" notifications? Maybe we should just add *all of them*, both approval and rejections...

Comment: @Dan I could do that.. However, my primary concern is users who have really done something *wrong*. It would of course make sense to show both accepted and rejected, I wonder though why nobody's brought that up before..

Comment: How do I upvote this original question, but not the update?  The update is really just a link to an answer with a different resolution than the post was requesting?  This should have been handled via a comment on that answer and not an update to the original question, since the original question was already considered by so many people.

Comment: As "edit was rejected" notification message was not implemented (despite to "status-completed"), the new ["Add global notifications for rejected edits (No, I don't mean the edit warning prompt)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295398/add-global-notifications-for-rejected-edits-no-i-dont-mean-the-edit-warning-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) feature request is available for vote(it is not a duplicate)

Comment: [...] *unless they critically checked each suggestion in their profile. I doubt anybody would do this* Speak for yourself. - I do this ***frequently***! And I sometimes do it *even* if my suggested edit was **accepted**.

Answer (score 128):

Kevin implemented this as described below. One rejected edit will produce the following warning:

[image: Attention! Your last edit was rejected]

That links back to the last edit that was rejected. If the editor *never* gets any edits approved, they'll see this every time they go to edit, until they're banned. If *some* are approved but many are rejected (see details below), they'll get a more noticeable warning:

[image: Warning! Some of your previous edits were rejected]

...Which links to /users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions. <strike>We're not *currently* indicating whether these have been approved or rejected on that page.</strike> **UPDATE (December 10, 2014):** [We now show suggested edit outcomes on that page (pending, approved, or rejected)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history).

Finally, there's an in-between warning that'll appear for folks who get *most* of their edits approved but have a few declines (see below for details):

[image: Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected]

Again, this links to the viewer's suggested edit history, and should allow conscientious editors to find past edits even when their most recent edit was approved.

---

I like this idea, but I also agree with [Jeff's concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/123439#123439) that this is the wrong way to be using notifications. In particular, if we're notifying you of stuff that doesn't *encourage* you and that you *can't do anything about*, it's unlikely to have a positive effect.

I think the right way to expose these rejections is to put them where they matter most: on the edit form itself, the next time you go to make an edit!

### Proposal: edit form warnings

Here's the default message that a low-rep user sees when suggesting an edit:

> [image: Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed]

There's a constant within the system that determines a minimum number of edits that must be made in a week before editors are eligible for a ban due to rejected edits. We'll refer to it here as `RejectionsTillBanned` (note that approved edits effectively increase this somewhat, but let's ignore that for now).

#### When # of edits by the current editor in the past week is less than RejectionsTillBanned

...then the system looks only at the last edit reviewed when determining whether or not to warn.

- If that edit was approved, no warning is given - the default message is shown.
- If that edit was rejected, the following message is appended to the default:

  > Attention! Your last edit was rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should [review the reasons given for rejecting it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4555211) before continuing.

#### When # of edits by the current editor in the past week is >= to RejectionsTillBanned

...then the system will calculate the following value, considering all edits suggested and reviewed in the past week except for those rejected by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1): `Rejected - Approved/3`

- If the result is >= 1 then the following message is appended to the default:

  > Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should [review your recently-rejected edits](/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before continuing.
- If the result is >= 3 then the following message is appended to the default:

  > **Warning!** Some of your previous edits were rejected. Please [review your recently-rejected edits](/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before continuing. Too many rejected edits may cause your editing privileges to be suspended.

#### Displaying the outcome of the edit on the activity list

**UPDATE (December 10, 2014):** [We now show suggested edit outcomes in the activity list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history) Original text follows:

In order for this proposal to be effective for prolific editors, it's essential that they're able to quickly identify *which* edits have been rejected. slhck's second suggestion is a good one, but his mockup breaks the ability to quickly scan the list when *not* filtering. So I'm proposing a slight variation on that:

> [image]

Pretty easy to pick out the outliers there now, eh?

#### Expectations

For users whose last edit (or edits) have been rejected, they get that warning and a link to information on why. But not in their inbox, not as a notification, not as an interruption to something else they might have been doing - as a *context-sensitive warning that they're about to do something they've been unsuccessful at in the past*. If there's something they can learn from the rejection reasons, *this* is the time for them to learn it.

Comment: Oh, see, I haven't been thinking about this at all. That makes a lot of sense when put into context! It would probably make sense to add a similar message to the flagging dialog if $number of flags have been declined.

Comment: @slhck: yeah, that's where this occurred to me actually. Aside: tired of running into users who make dozens of bad edits / leave dozens of bad flags and only realize too late that they've done anything wrong; banning (and in particular hell-banning) is the wrong way to deal with users who honestly *do* want to learn.

Comment: +1 I like this. But they still have the problem of being routed to their suggested edit feed, and not been able to see, at a glance, which of their edits were approved/ rejected. ([e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)) Can this also considered as been shown when their rejection rate reaches X% ("WARNING: A large percentage of your [reject edits](http://google.com) have been rejected"), to catch the people who get a/r/a/r/a/r/a/r...

Comment: Agreed with @Matt — Shog9, the initial suggestion by the currently top voted answer (namely showing exactly which edits were accepted or rejected) is not orthogonal to your approach, but would be a useful addendum for those who actually check their profile.

Comment: @Matt / slhck - sure, that's a fine suggestion. But it is, as you say, somewhat orthogonal to this feature-request.

Comment: @Shog9: I'd prefer to describe it as "the icing on the cake" ;).

Comment: I disagree that notifications are inappropriate, but as long as the information reaches the user (as opposed to being hidden deep inside their profile, undiscoverable and difficult to reach even if you know where to look), I'm happy. I would prefer to see “you had N edits rejected recently:”, followed a list of the edits that the user hadn't yet been notified about. (@Matt Not a percentage, that's useless. And each rejection must be shown, not just when there are very many of tehm, otherwise you stop improvement after users have gone beyond mediocre.)

Comment: I also like this solution better because the message is displayed on the site where the problem edit occurred. Why tell me my Project Management SE edits suck when I'm making SO edits for which I have a great track record. +1

Comment: I agree with this, although to be fair, Jeff's response was when you'd get Ol' Orange Slidy for a notification...which was pretty significant harassment. I hardly notice Lil' Blue Circly to begin with, so the negative impact that comes with an in-your-face taunt is probably a little less. A context sensitive warning makes far more sense either way though, to the point where I'd also recommend it for the edge case where someone has a few recent edits rejected and then hits 2000 reputation, since they'd still potentially need to brush up on what makes a good edit.

Comment: What will "rejected" link to?  Will it be easy to see what edits have been recently rejected, and what the reasons have been?  Perhaps this warning should include the most common rejection reason for recent rejected edits, rather than just a paraphrase of the minor edit rejection reason.

Comment: Well, what if you [COULD so something about your rejected edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113727/how-can-i-appeal-a-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit)?

Comment: BUT there is something you can do about it! examine your behavior and change it or revisit it before yuo are banned..  Also like @DanDascalescu idea.

Comment: @shog9 This still seems like a super relevant feature request - any update on whether this is planned?

Comment: @Shog9, given the success of the somewhat related [Allow recovery from flag hellban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405), I feel this should be revisited. Would it be a dupe to post something like your answer here as a new feature request? Or does a bounty on this question make sense, even though it's your answer I want to see implemented?

Comment: I fully agree with this proposal. Just *something* needs to be done here, I don't have any strong preferences for the way it's done or the specific calculations.

Comment: See edit, @mhlester. This is *based* on the flag warning thing, but with some variations due to the nature of the system.

Comment: That's *fantastic*. I love it! Fingers crossed for an implementation. It really does seem like it could help a lot. Would have helped me in my infancy.

Comment: Good thing robo-reviewers only approve stuff, not reject them... right?

Comment: @boltClock, nothing wrong with burning the candle at both ends though, right? Less crap gets robo-approved if there's less crap submitted

Comment: The yellow mark on "rejected" and the green mark on "approved" - I think they are great - too bad they're gone :(

Answer (score 66):

I don't agree with a banner appearing every time one of your edits is rejected, but I could get behind one of the following alternatives.

1. Update **Profile » Activity » Suggestions** to show which edits were accepted and which were rejected without forcing the user to manually click on each one. I prefer this solution because it is unobtrusive and makes the **Suggestions** tab more useful, in my opinion.

   > [image]
2. Show a new message in the user's inbox for each rejected edit. I don't really like this solution because it is a bit intrusive, but it's *definitely* better than a banner.

In general, I agree with Jeff that positive feedback is better than negative feedback. That being said, any feedback at all is better than none.

Comment: I like approach no. 1, maybe it could be combined with a positive/neutral indicator of recent changes, like "You have *X* new edit decisions" or something. I also added a screenshot to show what it could look like.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the mockup! That's pretty much exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Approach #2 does seem a bit intrusive, but perhaps it could be improved by only delivering a message after N consecutive rejections, where N=5 or something like that.

Comment: Strongly disagree that they need an *inbox* notification for every rejected edit. However, for edits rejected *with a custom message* this would be appropriate.

Comment: Approach #1 would not work, because that's what it looks like when a user *actually does that action* on a suggested edit. When viewing it in the [all] tab, it would look like the user actually voted to approve the suggested edit, not that it was their suggested edit which was approved. Related: [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122581/141525)

Comment: @Shog9 Any thoughts about at least implementing change #1 from Chris Frederick's answer?

Comment: Now that we have the new notifications system, this is somewhat moot; the notifications system is designed exactly for things like this.

Comment: @slhck: see my answer here - rather than a passive irritation, this feedback should be presented to the user in the context where it matters *most*.

Comment: @Shog9 Since you haven't directly answered my question: Any chances that #1 from Chris' suggestions gets implemented? There's no harm done from that, it's just terribly useful information to have right where it's needed the most. (See also: [Users who want to find their rejected edits](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5212/where-do-i-see-my-rejected-suggested-edits))

Comment: Well I was just banned from editing posts, as I did not know that I was rejected some suggestions. So having the banner appear is a good idea.

Comment: Approach #1 has officially been implemented.

Answer (score 44):

Why is everyone saying that bad things can't appear in notifications?

I'll give you two scenarios:

1. I am a vandal. I make spam edits on a load of tag wikis. The edits get rejected and I get told why. I would ignore them. **This scenario is null. Nothing would change either way.**
2. (This recently happened to me) I am a good faith editor. I edit, but do something wrong (provide too simple info or something). I get told what is wrong, so I change my behavior and all is good. **This is the real thing. Without the warnings, the editor would get blocked, because he does not know what he is doing wrong, and would naïvely carry on. With the warnings, he can become a better editor.**

How can these notifications do any harm? All they will do is stop users like me getting blocked when they were **editing in good faith**.

Comment: Precisely my point. Thank you. Users edit because they want to do something good to the site – and you need some kind of feedback when you're on the way.

Comment: Totally. I recently got blocked when I didn't know what I was doing wrong, and all that block has done is mean that some of my knowledge and willingness-to-help is not transferred to the site.

Comment: Another alternative would be [changing the edit limit for tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136934/changing-the-edit-limit-for-tag-wikis)

Comment: ACarter - See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/155826) and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136479/155826). This feature can *definitely* be implemented without using notifications, which have been *designed* to be for positive, "atta-boy" type information. I especially like Shog9's answer because he addresses the problem when it matters most, right before the editor attempts to make another potentially bad edit. In both of those scenarios, the editor *would not get blocked*. And if that person doesn't read the information, notifications won't matter either.

Comment: @jmort, If I had got the notifications, I would not have been blocked. Having the notice above the editor is probably a better idea, but as long as the editor finds out and does not get blocked, it doesn't matter a great deal. (I have also upvoted both those answers.)

Comment: We need for a notification. *Any* time I make an edit, answer, etc. it is for the purpose of providing useful information for everyone, not for myself.  If it is rejected, I need to know it happened in order to correct the information so I can repost it in a better way.  Simply losing the info forever with no notification is ridiculous. No responsible contributor would be okay with simply losing their info they provided without having the *immediate* opportunity to fix their edit, i.e., notification. Such people could optionally turn off a notification I guess.

Answer (score 33):

I asked a similar question - see [Also show rejection vote reasons for accepted suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127136/show-rejection-reasons-for-suggested-edits-in-the-global-inbox) - that has been closed as a duplicate of this one.

It was not en exact duplicate: what happened to me was that my edit was actually accepted, but there was one reject vote with a useful comment. I think that in such a case the chances of missing the comment are even higher that if the edit was actually rejected: I had no reason to go and dig up the comment.

My vote would be to have a notification in the inbox with the comment.

There are ways to criticize something without saying 'you suck' - altough probably as techies we are not very good at that.

Comment: Now that we have notifications in general put in the tab next to this one, this is now the best option.

Answer (score 30):

I understand the desire to educate, but there's something deeply wrong about the proposed design.

The net effect is the user seeing this broadcast in their face in the most obtrusive way we can:

> You've done something wrong. Click [here](http://example.com) to learn why you suck.

**You should only send the user obtrusive 'in-your-face' messages about how awesome they are.**

Messages about non-awesomeness should always be delivered quietly, via a backchannel, in a way that minimizes their impact. Otherwise, we're slapping them in the face.

Comment: Given that how few rejected edits there are, would this really be a problem? Isn't downvoting and closing the same? How else can users know they did something wrong?

Comment: @slhck While most edits are approved I think [29,000 rejected](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62460/suggested-edits-rejections-approvals) edits is still a lot

Comment: Exactly. People who care have access to the information to learn from the outcome of their suggestions (though maybe that should be made more readily available), but shoving it in their face at every turn will just punish them for (usually) trying to help. Not to mention the fact that any proposal that causes that annoying bar to appear *more* often is inherently evil.

Comment: Look, man, you're going to be gone in a week anyways. Now is the _perfect_ time to pull this sort of stunt. Next week, waffles can just shrug and say "Look, that was all Jeff, and we don't know where he put the keys, so we can't undo it right now... we'll get back to you."

Comment: @slhck I am not objecting to the desire to educate, merely the mechanism that was proposed.

Comment: I can understand that notifications shouldn't be too much "in your face", but maybe edit decisions could be summarized, like the "You have *X* favorite changes" notification bar, and the tab in the profile could say *"accepted"* or *"rejected"* instead of *"suggested"*, including the blue highlighted number in the tab name.

Comment: Okay, for a serious comment: I can get on board with the philosophy here, but the problem is that the current system doesn't match the "quietly, via a backchannel" setup. Edit suggestors aren't being notified __at all__ of what happens to their work, and it's not even easy for the ones who have initiative to hunt that information down.

Comment: Maybe show the result of the last 10 edit suggestors a user made when they go to do their next edit suggestor?

Comment: I disagree. If you have a rejected edit, you need to know that it has been rejected so that in the future, you can make better edits.

Comment: No need for the banner anymore. The new notifications are much less obtrusive. Besides, it's not much different from post edit announcements: "What you posted was wrong or incomplete. Fortunately, someone else fixed it for you."

Comment: Jeff, that is a cultural thing. In some countries/cultures, it is *expected* you say your critique straight up, not hide it behind pleasantries. In this instance, I think the need for "training" outweighs the need for "don't tell me I'm doing something wrong".

Comment: @Raphael - We need a setting called "Enable 'You suck' notifications" for the people who culturally expect to see this type of thing ;)  All joking aside, see [my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136479/155826), which demonstrates how to achieve this feature without the "in your face" notifications. Will this be a good start to helping reduce the number of rejections while still being culturally sensitive to those who don't expect criticism broadcasts?

Comment: [This user is a perfect example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136915/tag-editing-limits-give-us-a-chance) for someone who wants to be told what the review results of his edits are. He was banned from editing for a week because he never noticed his edits got rejected, so he had no (accessible) way to actually learn what a good edit is.

Comment: As for "in your face": another oblivious user, who's [feeling a bit embarrassed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits#comment398335_140938) not knowing they were doing things wrong, and then being explained in public when asking about the disabled edit link...

Comment: @Jeff right now people [wonder where their edit disappeared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143465/my-edit-keeps-getting-removed) - I am sure it happens to great many they just don't bother to go asking in Meta. So we do need some mechanism to tell the user what happened to his/her suggested edit, don't you think?

Comment: I would also like to be notified when my edits are rejected. Make it an option then, if you think it's rude or whatever to notify everyone.

Comment: Don't agree (respectfully). A "silent rejection" as I have experienced recently is more of a slap-in-the-face.

Comment: Suck?! That's not a good word.

Answer (score 25):

The new notification system has successfully reduced the amount of noise from items that are not actionable, such as privilege changes, badge awards, and so forth. These notifications appear in the top left menu, not just for one site, but for every site on the network. As a result, notifications are less noisy but more visible, since Stack Exchange can push notifications to me for Site A even though I am on Site B.

### **Problems with using notifications:**

Adding suggested edit results to this notification box creates two problems:

- It significantly increases the amount of noise based on the number of rejected edits.
- It doesn't match Jeff's goal of not saying "YOU SUCK" in the notification section.

While we definitely want to help people improve their edits, we don't want to change the positive tone of the notifications system. Right now, Stack Exchange only sends positive reinforcing messages that are intended to increase the frequency of a specific set of behaviors, and we should ensure that it stays that way.

In other words, even though these notifications aren't as "loud", we still don't want them to have negative connotations.

### **Use "Helpful Flags" as a template:**

With that said, let's use the helpful flags statistics as a template for how to approach this problem. When I flag a post, I'm never told how much I suck because I flagged a post incorrectly. However, at a glance, my profile does show how helpful I've been. If I click on the helpful flag value, I see a list of all of my flags, as well as the detailed results.

If a flag is declined. I see the message from the moderator explaining why. Again, this information is never pushed and is something I must explicitly look for.

If we take this same approach with suggested edits, we have something similar to what appears in this User Profile mockup. See the "Stats" section at the bottom of the User Information section:

**User Profile Helpful Edits:**

[image: User Profile with Suggested Edit stats]

In this example, there are 19 helpful edits which the community approved. Again, the information is positive and reinforcing.

If I click on the helpful edit value, I'm taken to a helpful edits detail page. This page resembles the helpful flag detail page. On this page, I see every edit I've made, in chronological order, and the results of each suggested edit. See attached mockup for a visual representation of what this feature would look like:

**Proposed Helpful Edits Detail Page:**

[image: Helplful Edits Detail Page]

In this detail page, I can review my suggested edits and take action in my next set of edits to ensure they're most helpful. In this example, one of my edits was rejected because I only tried editing the tags and nothing else. It was rejected for being too minor and because there is an "edit tags" link that I can use to change the tag, assuming I have enough reputation to do so.

In summary, this solution balances positive, reinforcing messages with low notification noise while still making it easy for a user to review his or her suggested edit history.

Comment: This is not a bad idea. The problem though is that flags and edits are conceptually different. While flags are being handled by moderators, edits can be approved by (almost) anyone, or at least a vast number of people who don't know what they're doing. Plus, the "helpful" edit count can never rise once you reach 2k (or 20k for tag wikis). Whether this is a real argument against your solution, I don't know. Anyway, if there's really no change in the "We don't want negative messages" mentality, then this would be a viable option.

Comment: The shoe will still fit, it's just going to be a different kind of shoe, one that SE would be comfortable wearing because of the positive/negative argument. I think you have a point that after 2k rep helpful edits are approved right away, but there are lots of things that change as we progress. For instance, after achieving the Deputy badge or the Copy Editor badge, the review section will no longer show your progress towards these goals. You also touched on another point that I feel needs to be addressed: The edit approvers need coaching too.

Comment: As a user, I expect notifications to include ALL messages, even if some of them are not positive. Notifications inform users about changes in reputation and comments, even if they may be negative, and no one complain about it.

Answer (score 13):

I think it's important to show this feedback not only to users who are suggesting edits, but also to reviewers who are approving and rejecting them.

At the same time, I agree with Jeff that the banner system is for "wow, you're awesome" messages only.

In regards to the feedback, if I were spending my valuable time suggesting edits, only to find out weeks or months later that they all were rejected because I was doing something wrong that I actually thought was helpful, I would surely want to know. While I agree with Jeff in that we don't want to flash banners, there should in fact be a very easy-to-get-to method of seeing the results of suggested edits and reviews, similar to how I can see why a flag may have been declined by a moderator.

Not making this information easily available shows disrespect to the people trying to help in assuming that we'll be offended by being shown or guided into doing it the right way.

Perhaps a modified version of [Chris Frederick's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123452/155826) where I click a "suggested edit results" section, similar to the "review" section. This wouldn't be mixed in with my normal question, answer, comment activity, but it **would be available for me to review should I feel the need to.**

As for reviewers, when I first started reviewing edits, I was approving tag edits, not realizing users without full edit privileges could simply click a "retag" link that disappears once you get full edit permissions at 2000 reputation. I later learned in a meta post that this was incorrect and that I should have rejected those edits. Meanwhile, I thought the people rejecting those edits were being ridiculous because I had no way to tell why they chose to reject.

Today, I see some rejections for edits that should not be rejected, perhaps due to the same ignorance now experienced by another new reviewer.

With the current system, it's not possible to help guide these users, both the ones making the edits and the ones approving and rejecting. I am for giving the feedback to those users who are interested and simply making it available for the ones who simply make suggestions without caring about the result.

Comment: I think part of the problem is also that the criteria for what should and shouldn't be approved is very ambiguous. We have "too minor" as a reject option, but then we've also heard that "any improvement is a good improvement". Not sure how we rectify that, though, either.

Comment: I think if there isn't much to improve, then a minor edit is ok. I typically accept minor edits unless I see a whole bunch of other typos, mispellings, grammar issues and formatting issues. If I have to edit the post myself for more than just a few missed items, I don't mark the suggested edit as helpful. I'm not sure if that's the right approach, but it is one that makes sense to me.

Comment: That's exactly my approach. At least there are two of us being consistent about it. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think a notification (in addition to the suggestions view showing the approval status) would be helpful. But not one for every edit, but more a summary à la

> Of your 17 recent suggested edits, 12 were approved

There may still be the unpleasant experience of "none were accepted", but if that really happens often said user *should* really consider their editing skills. In that case a helpful link to a "What is a good edit?" [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post might be helpful.

Comment: "A helpful link [...] might be helpful". Indeed m-/

Answer (score 1):

In the mean-time, it is just about possible to get a list of your rejected edits (more easily than clicking through Every. Single. Edit. on one's profile to check, that is) using StackExchange data explorer and a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM SuggestedEdits WHERE RejectionDate is not null AND OwnerUserId = MY_ID
```

(where `MY_ID` is your SO user ID).

An example showing [my rejected edit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/77610).

Comment: Only problem is that the SEDE data is always outdated.

Comment: @slhck by how much? I only discovered it yesterday.

Answer (score -9):

Yes... no.

Admittedly, it is inefficient.  However, in the end, edits aren't all that relevant. They don't benefit you a whole lot, they just benefit the community.

Here's the main problem however: if this was implemented, there would be hordes of people who would say things like what BoltClocks suggested.  Although I'm not against the idea itself, it (at least seems like it) would lead to useless notification ideas like:

- Let's notify people when someone replies the comment replying to their comment!
- Let's notify people when someone posts another answer on a question they also answered!
- Let's notify people so that they know stack overflow is broken!
- etc, etc.

Although I myself would like this, it would contribute to the notification spam that I'm always getting. So please, please, [Keep it simple, (not so) stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Of course you have a point. I've always liked the fact that you don't get notifications for everything, but **an edit being rejected just vanishes somewhere in the profile**. It's not like you could even easily research this yourself. Users that suggest invalid and harmful edits will never receive any feedback about how "bad" they acted. The other cases you mention are always "positive" notifications (except for a "broken SO account", I don't know what you mean by that).

Comment: But the hordes of people can be asked to make their suggestions in other meta questions. Then the bad suggestions (useless notification ideas) can be downvoted with an explanation like this and won't be implemented.

Comment: Uh, flags are a whole different matter altogether. Users need to know what we moderators tell them about their flags, I'd even say more so than what the community tells them about their edit suggestions.