# Also show rejection vote reasons for accepted suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, notifications, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

This is an extension to the feature request [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).

I edited a question on Stack Overflow, and my proposed changes went into the suggested edit queue. What happened to me was that my edit was actually *accepted*, but there was one reject vote with a useful comment.

The rejection had a useful explanation, but in order to find it I had to dig quite a bit. In most cases, I would have missed it. I think that in such a case the chances of missing the comment are even higher that if the edit was actually rejected: I had no reason to go and dig up the comment.

I think it would be a good idea if the user was notified of any vote to reject one of their suggested edits in the global inbox. That way, it would be easier for them to see which of their edits (even if ultimately accepted) were disliked, and a message that might tell them how to improve in the future. This is particularly true given that, as I understand it, the purpose of the suggested edits feature is to "train" new users in the ways of editing. My vote would be to have a notification in the inbox with the comment. There are ways to criticize something without saying 'you suck'.

Comment: +1 for being responsible and keeping track of your edit suggestions. If only all souls were as great as yours. *bows*

Comment: Every time this is brought up, someone mentions that such a feature *could* contribute to edit wars.  I guess I'll be that guy this time.

Comment: But it *could* also help in effective rejections based on something the other person missed. This is a community moderated site, clear information sharing is crucial. You have my vote.

Comment: This could also result in contested edits being brought up a lot more.

Comment: I don't see how it would lead to edit wars @Charles. Do you mean more along the lines of Ben's comment, that it would lead to more discussions about "why was my edit rejected?" or along the lines of "I disagree with the rejection reason provided for this edit"?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: thanks for the better English

Comment: @MiMo: I edited your question to include your comments at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128877/146243, and added a preface to distinguish it from that question.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: thanks!