# Suggested edits that deserve to be an answer on its own

Tags: feature-request, answers, suggested-edits, review

I saw multiple suggested edits today that would have been good answers … I they weren't appended to an older post. When I see that someone put much effort in his (her) answer, then I don't to reject him with the standard reply:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

That's just mean.

Otherwise it would it be outright "theft" if I would post it as my answer and get the reps. And a community post would withhold the reps from its rightful owner, too.

So if I reject the suggested edit, I need a way to tell the poster to put a new answer, but messaging users is not too easy on SO.

It would be the best if you could modify the suggested edit to become an own edit:

- The suggesting user would be the owner of the new answer.
- The first revision of the new answer would be the answer be the be post, as if the suggested edit was confirmed.
- The second revision would be your edits to the answer.

Of course you would need to have two edit boxes: the original answer and the new answer.

I hope I made my feature request comprehensible. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `other` option on the reject edit form? You can fill in a (short) free-form message there informing the user they should post their suggested edit as an answer instead.

[image: Reject other option, with freehand circle (drawn with trackball)]

Comment: That's what I did. I don't think a casual user will look if his answer was excepted or not. (If I'm remembering correctly there was no message when your suggested edit was excepted or rejected.)

Comment: No, suggested edits are listed on your activity tab, but I don't think rejected edits result in a notification, indeed.

Comment: @Kay I agree, I think they removed notification a month or two ago. The only time I'd know is if I noticed a rep change.

Comment: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Comment: @Flexo this is never going to happen, though. Jeff is adamant that the inbox should never be used to say `Hey, you suck. Click [here] to learn why.`

Comment: @gobernador Jeff is gone (or differently involved) and 140 upvotes suggests he's in a minority. It doesn't have to be as tasteless as "hey you suck" either.

Comment: [Suggested edits that change links should jump out and punch reviewers in the face](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142919/suggested-edits-that-change-links-should-jump-out-and-punch-reviewers-in-the-fac)