# Suggested edits that change links should jump out and punch reviewers in the face

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, spam

This request is motivated by a [sneaky sneaky spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142887/spam-edit-approved) who replaced a useful link with a link to some youtube video. It fooled several reviewers, and if I hadn't noticed that the link text was the same, but the link was highlighted as changed, I might have missed it too. If he'd also changed the link text to "PhoneGap Future Plugin Support" it would be a rare reviewer that would have noticed it.

This got through because of something unique to links; I think they're the only allowed element with hidden information (the url). To counter this, I think the review page should show a list of any changes made to links in a new section above the main diffs:

[image: mockup]

It might also be helpful if clicking the `[1]` would trigger a little javascript arrow pointing out where that link is within the post.

Comment: Clicked for description of *punch reviewers in face* implementation. Was disappointed.

Comment: Just use facepunch.js

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Sorry about that, it's just that I don't know [python](http://xkcd.com/353/)

Comment: @BenBrocka - is that a JQuery plugin?

Comment: Maybe we should make it show the markdown diffs by default.

Comment: [Here's a really bad one - more offensive than spam, but same principle.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4223990)

Answer (score 26):

It occurs to me that these are pretty obvious *when you're viewing the Markdown diff:*

[image: Suggested edit showing markdown diff]

Perhaps it would be feasible to *force* this view (along with a short bit of text explaining *why*) when reviewing an edit that changes hyperlinks? For example,

[image: No choice but to view it in the raw]

This *might* also improve the situation when reviewing [legitimate edits that *fix* broken links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207225/should-i-edit-an-accepted-answer-which-need-updating-because-the-urls-have-chang), as the Markdown diff makes it more obvious that the edit is substantial and useful.

Comment: Don't force, please. Just make it appear by default even if your last view was rendered output.

Comment: Does it make sense to also display the ol' "our servers think this may be spam. review carefully" banner any time a link is changed?

Comment: Really don't want folks getting blase about that particular notice, @mhlester.

Comment: ok that's a good point. better to start from the assumption it's valid than cry wolf

Answer (score 19):

Following [Shog9's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207237/115866), the review interface will initially show the Markdown diff for suggested edits that change links (from the next build on). You can still switch to the rendered diff; we're just making the Markdown diff the first thing you see in such a case, regardless of which diff view you usually prefer.

If only the link *text* changed, but the link *target* stayed the same and the link wasn't otherwise moved around, this will not count as a changed link for these purposes. Edits like that are easily visible and reviewable in the rendered diff.

Comment: Could you display a notification when the markdown view is forced? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273197/a-better-way-to-spot-spam-edits-introducing-spurious-links#comment103535_273206

Comment: That seems more like a theoretical problem to me. If you feel strongly about it, please open a feature request; this shouldn't be in a comment thread.

Comment: balpha would feature request at MSO referred by @Stijn do? [A better way to spot spam edits introducing spurious links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273197/839601) (I saw the example edit that introduced spam there and it was... scary - I am rather experienced editor and reviewer, but I could easily miss that fraud)

Comment: [It might be useful to expand this feature to when HTML comments are edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304189/349538).

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend that when a link is changed, it turns some shade of red. Also, that a changed link would trigger a popup (the orange box) that notifies a reviewer that a link has been changed in the edit.

i.e. if I were to change a link from `download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html` to `www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq8U8L_MfK8`, a popup like the "you may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds. (click this box to dismiss)", but instead says "A link has been changed in this edit (click this box to see the change)".

The first link is a the javadoc Scanner page, the second is a discus drill video from youtube

Comment: If we can't get the page to punch the reviewer in the face, this is the next best option

Comment: I still say we hold out for the punching. Whoever could develop that feature would make *millions*. Let's start with youtube comments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this punches the reviewers hard enough:

[image: link change as a supernova]

I have implemented a userstyle that highlights any edited link, whether it is the URL that changes or just the description:

http://userstyles.org/styles/98439/suggested-edit-face-punch

Of course, this doesn't fix the problem for reviewers that just don't care. However, it helps reviewers that do care. Because otherwise [links in changed text are literally invisible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222385/the-side-by-side-diffs-should-make-it-clear-when-a-link-is-added?lq=1).

Just for completeness, here is the source code for the style:

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("stackapps.com"), domain("mathoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com") {
.body-diffs a .diff-add {color: white; background-color: #FE7A15}
}
```

Also, a neccessary attribution: Colors shamelessly borrowed from the Stack Overflow supernova (pending flag topbar icon).