# Abuse of "This edit is too minor ..." hinders link and spelling correction

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Why do reviewer block improvements of tag wikis, which just fix spelling and broken links? Is it more important to have larger edits than better content? And why is there no flag option to report such cases?

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3277792

If the reason is that some reviewers are bored accepting smaller fixes, what could be done to ensure that improvements are not stopped by the moods of these community members?

Comment: for what it's worth, I would have approved. It's NOT minor, probably people didn't notice you changed links - fixing even one dead link with working link is enough IMO. Tag wikis tend to be more "sensitive", so those who review such suggestions are generally more "trigger happy" with rejecting. That said, there's no "abuse" here and no need to flag anything. Just try again.

Comment: It was on the cusp of being approved so clearly a decent number of people thought it was worth approving

Comment: Reviewers should notice changed links announced in the change comment.

Comment: Regarding "notice changed links", it's already a very popular [request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142919/152859). Regarding your edit, "what could be done to ensure that improvements are not stopped by the moods of these community members?" - nothing, we can't and we won't change human nature and free will decisions.

Comment: One workaround, if you spot something that needs to be fixed but is "too minor" and you don't have enough rep, is to head to the site's general chat (or meta.se's chat) and ask if somebody will change it. If you suggestion makes sense usually there's somebody around with enough rep who will do it (or who will eventually read the request and do it).

Answer (score 1):

Minor edits cause more work than they get done. It has to be reviewed by multiple people.

We want editors to learn that. That is why minor suggested edits get rejected. Not because the edit is bad in general but because such minor edits should be done by users having enough rep without going to the review system.

Besides that specific tag is a good example what tags are not. We want a short description of the topic in a tag description and not a tutorial.

Comment: Well, spotting and correcting errors as posted above needs more time than 3 positive reviews of such edits. Therefore, I don't really understand your argument.

Comment: Is it necessary to occupy 3 reviewers for the content you changed? Was the edit that important? If not, don't suggest an edit.

Comment: Is reviewer's time more valuable as the time of other users?

Comment: @BHF 3 people's time is, that said I'm not sure I agree your edit was too minor (possibly on a bad tag wiki but thats secondary); theres nothing obvious that you missed

Comment: And BTW we want reviewers not just scan an edit for a few seconds and click *approved*.

Comment: But why does http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing not state, please do not fix links, spelling and grammar if you don't have 2000 rep?

Comment: @BHF it is present on the edit suggestion page itself: "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary."

Comment: Which doesn't change the fact that this answer missed that there was a link fix happening as well

Comment: If I edit a tag wiki the info is just "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed." The "We welcome all..." part does not appear.

Comment: Dead links should stay around if the person who finds them doesn't have 2k rep to be able to edit a post without needed int reviewed?