# Should I edit an accepted answer which need updating because the URLs have changed or make a new answer?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have tried to edit this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12682865/1654241) because 3 out of the 4 URL are dead because the site has moved.

My 2 edit suggestions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3348721) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3348974)) have been rejected even though they improve the answer by correcting the URL which have become incorrect.

Why is that so?

Comment: I would have accepted them. I guess it's one of those cases where, as a reviewer, if you're not sure, you should simply skip.

Comment: I probably would've just said "Fixed broken links" as an edit comment - short and simple, less likely to get rejected.

Comment: So, do you think I should try to edit it a third time with the same edit and "Fixed broken links" as the edit comment or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you able to point to a page that leads from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/ that points to this new update site?

Comment: @Duncan JadClipse has no relation at all to JD-Eclipse except both are Eclipse plugins that decompile Java classes on the fly. JadClipse uses Jad and JD-Eclipse uses JD-Core (which have no relation too).

Comment: Ahah, that explains my confusion! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a shame that edit was rejected; fixing broken links is Really Important.

Out of curiosity, I suggested [more or less the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3349446) (anonymously) with the simple explanation "Fixed broken links"... And it was approved within minutes.

Sometimes, being direct is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

> So, do you think I should try to edit it a third time with the same
>   edit and "Fixed broken links" as the edit comment or is there a better
>   way?

No, don't edit again and again, it will consider as rude. Instead I would suggest you to inform the author through comment like "**link broken please fix it**".

Update: I think you don't have any other alternative, since you don't have the privilege to comment, I will comment the author on behalf of you.

Comment: Yeah I thought of it being rude trying to edit again (and if it still doesn't get approved, it would lower my rep of rightful editing). Problem is, I don't have enough rep to comment on posts which aren't mine so I can't do it.

Comment: Shog9 did the edit anonymously so you don't need to comment on the post, thank you.