# My edit keeps getting removed

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I'm trying to edit an answer on Stack Overflow, all seems to go well, I get a message with:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I revisited after about ten minutes, still the same. Half an hour later, the edit is gone and so is the notification. Nothing else, no message of my edit being declined. I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/users/696460/ambidex?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Show us the question and what you're trying to edit. It's probably being rejected for a good reason.

Comment: Also see [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters, that would be something I'd suggest too having been through this edit rejection process! I'll go upvote that request.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I don't think your explanation of the history of what a pixel means is necessary for the OP or other readers to understand what a pixel is. You have to remember that just because you suggest an edit it does not mean the community will think your edit is worthwhile. It can be rejected for various reasons, in this case I don't think the new information was helpful.

As others have stated, you don't get an inbox/notification message of any kind when an edit is rejected, but this information is available to you on [your profile's activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696460/ambidex?tab=activity).

Comment: I don't think that's what this question was about. The OP is just asking if he should have received a notification of the rejection.

Comment: Hi Aaron Bertrand, your spot on, about which question this is about. So I guess you're the mod that declined it. My edit was truly because the fixed which apparently are 0.25mm in metrics, which explained to me why thinking that a "pixel" is truly a hardware pixel is plain wrong. That's why I would most definitely suggest implementing that in the answer?

Comment: Nope, he is not the person who declined it. (Those are not necessarily mods anyway). Go to the page I stated in my answer. There you'll find its status and the decline reasons of the users who declined it.

Comment: @Ambidex, Aaron had nothing to do with rejecting your edits. As the other answer by Bart explains, you can get information about those rejections from your profile page, including the identity of the reviewers.

Comment: No, I am not a mod, nor did I have anything to do with rejecting this specific edit. I'm just looking at it now, after the fact, and guessing why it was rejected. How the notifications work (or should work) is not something I realized was part of the question.

Comment: Ah really sorry about this... I'm really new about all this, did not know you could review others declined edits. And the edit just "disapearing" just confused me a lot. Thanks @ all.

Comment: @Ambidex I am one of those who declined your first edit. Like already said, it's not proper to change someone else answer - you can post comment and ask the author to add such information but don't do that yourself.

Comment: Hi @ShaWizDowArd, thanks for your motivation. I did not see it before I read here that it's located under the activity tab. Actually, about the author, I actually did confirm with the author about the edit. He seemed cool with it. This was discussed in the chat I started later, thinking he declined the edit. (I removed the chat notification)

Comment: @Ambidex in such case you need to tell "author has asked me to do this edit" linking to some proof and it will likely get approved. The reviewers won't go and check everywhere for every suggestion they review.

Comment: Hi @ShaWizDowArd, I understand. :) I'll leave the answer like it is. But, I have to say... This is not actually the answer that answered my own question. But if the community thinks this answer suffices, I'll have to agree I guess. :)

Comment: @Ambidex you shouldn't accept an answer just because it has the most up-votes. You should accept the answer that best answered your question. If that's not my answer, I'm okay with that.

Comment: I've [requested the author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950421/element-sizes-in-pixels-why#comment15926047_11950422) to edit his original answer. Thanks for the help you guys! I'll be a good boy from now on... ;) I hope those edit rejection notifications will get built-in though...

Answer (score 3):

Go to your profile page. Under the Activity tab you will find a list of your activities. Limit it to "suggestions" if you must. There you will find your suggested edits. Clicking on them will lead you to the suggested edit and will show whether or not it has been accepted, reject or is still pending.

In your particular case, both the same edits have been rejected twice.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for this answer, it explains me how to get behind the edit motivation (which I couldn't find in the first place)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your [edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/350803) ([twice](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/350783)) for changing too much of the original post.

Please review [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work); it explains how edits are approved or rejected, and what is acceptable. Your edits were rejected by users with enough reputation to review suggested edits, not by a moderator.

You are not notified of the review decisions though; you can follow your progress per suggestion on your `activity` profile tab (select `suggestions` there).