# Are editors notified of improvements to their edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I improve a suggested edit, it is helpful to show the original editor which improvements were made to his suggestion. Does the original editor receive any feedback on the improvement of his edit?

For instance, often a title is improved, or spelling is corrected, but a "thank you" line is left as-is below the question. When editors get feedback on this, they'll probably do an even better job next time.

I don't expect editors to check back and review every edit they made (at least I don't).

Comment: I don't think so - only the OP is getting notified when his/her post is  being edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, editors never receive any feedback about their suggested edits. Not only they won't know that someone improved, [they won't even know whether the edit was approved or rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor). The only feedback suggesters ever receive is that if they have had too many suggestions rejected, they'll be banned from suggesting edits for a week.

If the suggester wishes to follow on the fate of the suggestion, they need to navigate to the activity tab in their profile, locate the edit and click on it (the accepted/rejected status is not shown in the profile). To see the nature of the improvement, they need click through to the post then to its history. It's a hassle even if the suggester does want to know.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. The linked question has some rationale as to why such feedback might not exist, that was helpful too.