# Notification when a suggested edit has been approved or rejected

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

I think it would be useful to see status updates on my suggested edits in the inbox or notifications, similarly to new comments on questions and answers.

As a new user I find it the current setup a bit discouraging... here's the story...

I saw an answer which I thought was missing something, so I edited it.
I saw the popup telling me that it will only be visible to me until the edit is reviewed.
Admittedly the edit was wrong, so it was rejected, and I didn't even see it myself anymore.

There was no indication, the change just disappeared, so I figured there has to be some kind of activity log in my profile, and indeed there was: Profile->Activity->Select the edit.
In my opinion that's a bit too many buttons to press to figure out what's going on.