# How do I find acceptance/rejection notes on Stack Overflow peer review for edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've recently tried an edit and it no longer appears as I edited. My initial guess was it was peer reviewed and the peer rejected the update. Assuming that is true, what is to be done then, when the edit is significant due to a fault in the code sample of the original un-edited answer?

Now I think otherwise, having read some similar Q-A on Meta.

It seems more likely that the view reverts after some minutes pass. Then, the original unedited answer appears. This does not indicate peer review rejection. Am I correct?

I don't know where to find peer review notes, or vote stats in the edit queue as I've learned it's called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/668836/tom-pace?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid code editing. They have a high risk of being rejected.  Try to focus on format and grammar issues.

Comment: What if the code editing is valid and the original answer was wrong (as in the case of my edits?) I can understand the approach to grammer and format being easier for general peer review, but this is a legit code fix.

Comment: See, this is the problem with suggested edits. The system doesn't bring it up to you if your edits get rejected. It just pretends the edits never happened if they get rejected, and files them away silently (where they're still reachable, but that's not the point...). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor

Comment: @TomPace - Then comment on that post and suggest author via comment. If he find it fine he will update the post himself.

Comment: Okay.  I can see that'd provide a path to a knowledgable peer review, since the original author would have the code and specific understanding and better chances of peer review success.  But it's still unfortunate my edits were rejected.

Comment: @TomPace - Don't worry! Rejection of suggested edit doesn't mean **the end of the world!** :)

Comment: Now I've added a bloated, deliciously unformatted commented full of code in that SO Q-A thread. :) Thanks for the suggestions everyone.  Next time, I'll just harass the incorrect answer poster.

Comment: I think SO has a self-contradictory position on editing. The aim is to maintain a high-quality repository of programming knowledge, using the voting and editing system to keep useful knowledge at the top of the list, but actually changing an incorrect answer is frowned on, and in particular, old answers are impregnable from a voting or commenting point of view. This is exactly the sort of bit rot old google groups posts suffer from and that SO's founders wanted to get rid of. I think meaning changes should be reviewed by people who understand the language and everyone else should skip.