# Is it prominent to a user if I reject a suggested edit with a custom message?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I do a lot of [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) stuff lately. Sometimes I reject suggested edits, because the editor makes changes in the source code (I'm not talking typos) or adds whole parts of explanation.

In such a case I leave a custom message like:

> Please add this as a comment, that the user can update his question/answer.

But I wonder whether this is read by the user or is it likely to go under? Is this prominent? Is it displayed in the **inbox** from the *StackExchange menu*?

In my profile I can find it under "*activity/suggestions*" but I don't think that I got any notification about it. I'm only aware because I think that some suggestions might get lost that way.

Comment: There's no notification AFAIK, but the activity/suggestions page has links to pages which describe each review in detail, including which people reviewed it, whether they accepted or rejected the edit, and the reason for each rejection, including any custom descriptions entered by the reviewers.  So the information is there, for anyone interested in seeing how they are doing with their suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt any notifications are given when your edits are rejected - or why.

Comment: side note, in the case of the particular example you're using `invalid edit` applies, as that is used to say the edit is replying to the post (and therefore should be a comment).

Comment: User who get rejected enough times will eventually be blocked from suggesting further edits; then he'll most likely come here to Meta asking why. People will tell him "see your suggestions" and only then he will see what you wrote. Bit too late, but he'll see it. :)

Comment: @Servy Thanks for that note. I never read beyond "*This edit is incorrect […]*". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only prominent if the editor knows where to look.  Suggested edit status (both accepts and rejects) do not appear to the editor except when they look under their own activity, or (in the case of accepts) manually look at the suggested edit in the review history.  However, the editor will obviously know that an edit is accepted when they get the +2 rep.

**In your user activity:**

[image]

**And then only after clicking on the suggested edit:**

[image]

[Previous suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123439/182513) to make edit rejects appear in the inbox have been turned down because of the long standing belief that you don't actively tell users that they suck.

Comment: Plus, it'd overload the notification system...

Comment: On Stack Overflow, probably, but on smaller sites, it might be less of an issue.

Comment: My comment wasn't really serious. Though I do agree. =)

Comment: Thanks. Your last reference holds the simplest and best explanation why it isn't shown in the notification system. But in some cases it could be really helpful, if it was. And I'm only talking about those things I referred to in my question, like added code that could be useful or a better explanation than the one given. Maybe it would be nice to have a checkbox, like: "*Show in user's notifications.*". And then the moment I write this down I think: This could be misused. But you may get my point anyway.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I don't disagree.  I've thought that reject should be shown in the inbox for a variety of reasons, most significantly is for educational purposes.  How is someone supposed to learn **how** to edit if they aren't given feedback as to what they are doing wrong.