# Could we add a tab for rejected edits?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) post, but I was wondering if perhaps we could add a tab under activity for rejected edits. What I am suggesting if it is unclear is an additional tab that shows rejected edits.

Like this:
[image: Rejection button]

Comment: Rejected edits are already shown in the "suggestions" tab. Why split them out?

Comment: @AnnaLear They aren't shown whether they are rejected/accepted there unless you click the suggested edit part.

Comment: Slightly different approach: [show-the-outcome-of-suggested-edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230989/); just show the outcome in the suggestions tab

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this justifies filter/tab of its own. Instead, why not just add this extra details in the existing view?

> [image]

We already have the details when the edit was suggested so tooltip of the approved/rejected will show the time when it occurred and maybe even by whom.