# Can "Thanks for your edit!" banner be linkified with the Suggested Edit Link?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

When a user without editing privileges suggests an edit to the post, a banner gets displayed until it is reviewed. Can the banner also provide a link to the Suggested edit?

For example, I made an edit to a post on Unix&Linux.SE. Can the banner also link to my [Suggested Edit in Review Queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14840)?

> [image: fresh suggested edit]

---

I know I can access the link through my Profile → Activity → Suggestions. But linking it directly on the face of the post would have immense benefits:

1. I have been a prolific editor on Ask Ubuntu (my first encounter with Stack Exchange Network) with a lot of Rep derived through Suggestions. I didn't get to know about these suggested edit links until very late (I guess I already had got about 400 edit suggestions approved by the time this came to my knowledge).
2. This means I didn't know about [all these stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172333/205516) when it mattered the most.
3. I never got to know why my suggestions got rejected because of my ignorance.
4. This would help reduce the barrier between Reviewers and Editors.
5. This would also help in case of Anonymous edits. Right now, there is no way an anonymous editor can access it unless the edit gets approved and he comes back to go through the Revision page of that particular post in order to access the Suggested Edit Review link. If the edit gets rejected - it's the end of the road for that anonymous editor.

   I just made an anonymous edit on one of the SE sites where I don't have an account and already feel like it's the end of the road for me since I just can't access the review link unless it gets approved.

---

Possibly also expand the banner to mention that they can also access the link to the suggestion via Profile → Activity → Suggestions.

Comment: +1 linkification is double-plus-good!

Comment: I'm not a fan of linking *that* specific text. I'd rather see additional text like "View the suggestion." appended to the end of the sentence below it which is linked.

Comment: @animuson: I don't mind whatever way Devs and Community wants it to be linked - it was an example to get my point across. I would prefer a link to it somewhere in the banner and a reference that we may access the link later on from Profile > Activity > Suggestions.

Comment: @animuson I would rather make "peer reviewed" a link; it would not require any extra words.

Comment: Thanks for this. Never knew this stuff. Now I find I have 11 out of 15 edits rejected. More on that later no doubt...

Comment: I'd make the entire [until it is peer reviewed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) a link. -> What does "`until it is peer reviewed` mean?" Ahh, some aproved it. Great.

Comment: Can a link simply appear on any question with outstanding edits?

Comment: @DanBolser: Yes.. If there are outstanding edits to a post from **YOU**, then *only* **YOU** can see that banner. What I am asking is that till the time the banner gets displayed to you it also links you to the review page for it.

Comment: You are no more a <2K rep denizen in AU :P

Comment: I suggest only the “edit” from “Thanks for your edit!” should be the link text as it is more descriptive of what the target is.

Comment: Been wanting this forever!! It's really annoying that I have to open my profile, go to *Activity > Suggestions* and find the suggested edit. I often want to watch the accept/reject votes cast on an edit I suggested and I would love to have the notification be presented with a link so that I can watch more quickly and easily. **Sidenote:** If it wouldn't stress the servers, the notification could even AJAX-update to show the accept/reject vote counts!

Comment: Also, I don't really care what part of the notification is linked to the *suggested edit* page, as long as *something* is.

Comment: Related feature request regarding which text specifically gets linked: [Confusing linkification in "pending edit" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240740/201907)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [noted by nicael](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/240301/166017), the "thanks for your edit!" message on questions and answers now shows a link to the suggested edit review task.

One minor note: we display the same message on tag wiki pages as well, but we haven't implemented a link to the review task there. Tag wiki pages can have two pending suggested edits (one for the excerpt, and one for the body), but the message is only displayed once, so this format doesn't work for tag wiki pages.

**Update:** The links are now shown on tag wiki edit suggestions, with two separate banners.

Comment: ... yet? Are there plans to add that or it will have to wait?

Comment: @Unihedron Given how rare tag wiki edits are compared to edits on questions and answers, it's not a priority at the moment. We may come back to it eventually, but it probably won't be soon.

Comment: @Uni or in other words: "no". :)

Answer (score 15):

It was finally implemented. Thanks!

> [image]

Now "peer reviewed" links to the suggested edit!

Comment: Why "peer reviewed"? Why not "This edit"? [It's pretty confusing.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240740/201907)