# What proportion of the "Review suggested edits" pages are actually read by the editor?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I've just got the "Review suggested edits" privilege on stack overflow (which I'm probably more excited by than is rational). So far I’ve been trying to give personalised reject messages where appropriate; along the lines of “Try to correct all problems with a post; in this case you should also have removed the ‘Regards Sebastian’ as that is noise”.

However, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172828/can-thanks-for-your-edit-banner-be-linkified-with-the-suggested-edit-link) suggests that many suggested edits pages are simply never read.

Therefore I want to ask if there is any data available on what percentage of “Review suggested edits” pages are actually read by the editor. If it’s a reasonably high number then I’ll keep giving personalised feedback but if its 1% then I’ll probably start using the canned responses more.

Comment: Oops, I've been reviewing for the past 2 days as well but I haven't written a single personal response when I rejected an edit... Should I?

Comment: @Litso Now that is the question, i'm not sure. I only leave personalised messages 20-30% of the time anyway

Comment: Good question! My best guess is 0.5% of the editors bother to check this. However, custom message is good for other reviewers as well, not just the editors so I won't be deterred from writing them. :)

Comment: @Litso most of the time I feel no need, user can always ask on meta if generic message is too generic for him.

Comment: Edit review queue is so small, that OPs usually don't have time to check that, if they don't hang on SO/SE all the time.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech The response remains available even after the review is complete, for example here is one of mine from when I was <2K http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3027887 Which I can find from the activity tab on my profile

Comment: I have no clue what the actual percentage is, but from first hand experience, I would guess that a majority of new suggested editors (the ones who would benefit most from detailed and custom reject reasons) don't look at it because they don't know it exists.  This is where the feature request to show rejections to editors would beneficial

Comment: Releated (but not a dup): [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624/182513)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Don't the other reviewers just see a `"1"` under `"Custom"` (and not the actual message). You only see the message when you go back, i.e. when you see who approved and who rejected. That's how I remember it.

Comment: @Dukeling true, I meant those who see the suggestion after is was already reviewed and rejected so they can see why it got rejected and apply the same logic in their own reviews.

Comment: Sometimes happens to me that I realy take time to read the question, but because "Review suggested edits" queue is so short, when I'm done it has already been reviewed and my contribution was useless...

Comment: In my experience if you want someone to understand why their edit was too minor, go and edit the post yourself so that they can see your revision and notice all of the stuff that they should have done.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't see stats about this (either how often they are written, or how often they are read) with the SE API.