# Can "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed" link you to the review page?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

When I make an edit and then get the text "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed" am I just supposed to guess the URL for the peer review page? Can't you just link me there direct from the question? Am I missing something?

Comment: It should, it was already asked. Vote up and wait for the team. :)

Comment: This is now `status-completed` :D

Answer (score 4):

[This is suggested once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172828/can-thanks-for-your-edit-banner-be-linkified-with-the-suggested-edit-link), but it is not (yet) implemented.

However, you don't have to guess the URL for the peer review page: go to your profile, then go to the 'activity' tab, and then you see your activity: including your suggested edits!
If you only want to see your suggestions, select "suggestions". If an item of your activity is a suggested edit, then "suggested edit" is linkified: this link goes to the peer review page.

Comment: Implemented as at Sep 30 2014 :)