# Confusing linkification of the words "peer reviewed" in the message shown above a pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

Here's the message that appears at the top of a question after you've submitted a suggested edit:

[image: The message that appears after suggesting an edit]

The words "peer reviewed" were initially linkified (to point to the suggested edit review task) on around the beginning of October 2014, according to the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172828/201907).

However, I'm not quite sure **why the words "peer reviewed" are the words that are linked**. Upon initially looking at this message, *I had no idea how to get to my pending edit*!

To increase usability to the max, links should describe the content they point to.

Thus, the words that should be linkified here instead of the current "peer reviewed" should be "your edit", or, alternatively, "This edit".

Comment: Yeah, I had this same question when it was introduced on meta.

Comment: Not sure about it. The suggested edit page shows more than just the edit itself, it show the progress towards its approval or rejection.

Comment: Yes, and the main thing it shows is still the edit you made. The text "peer reviewed" doesn't really describe an edit. I was actually expecting it to be an explanation of the peer reviewing process or something.

Comment: Damn straight. Link text should describe the resource being linked to. This is _fundamental_ web engineering 101 and has been for _decades_.