# There should be a link to the review entry in the header after suggesting a tag wiki edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When you suggest an edit to a post and view the post while it's pending, [there's a link to the review in progress in the generated header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172828/274165). But as noted in the [dev answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240375/274165), this linking hasn't been implemented for tag wikis/excerpts yet, partly because there are potentially two links to include and the wording is not entirely obvious, and partly because they're orders of magnitude less common.

Here's my suggested wording for the three cases.

- #### Tag wiki excerpt only

  > **Thanks for your edit!**
  >   This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](http://$SITEURL/review/suggested-edits/$TAG_WIKI_EXCERPT_REVIEW_NUMBER).
- #### Tag wiki only

  > **Thanks for your edit!**
  >   This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](http://$SITEURL/review/suggested-edits/$TAG_WIKI_REVIEW_NUMBER).
- #### Both

  > **Thanks for your edit!**
  >   These edits will be visible only to you until they are peer reviewed ([tag wiki](http://$SITEURL/review/suggested-edits/$TAG_WIKI_REVIEW_NUMBER), [excerpt](http://$SITEURL/review/suggested-edits/$TAG_WIKI_EXCERPT_REVIEW_NUMBER)).

---

I can't directly address the prioritization of tag wiki edits, but I'd appreciate the corresponding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) or [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) mark, at least.

Comment: @AdamLear: Awesome, implementation looks quite solid!