# Unable to view tag edit review

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When submitting a question / answer edit (below reputation requirement for instant), you get a response box like this:

[image: box1]

However, when you edit a tag, you get:

[image: box2]

Notice the lack of the hyperlink, bringing you to the review.

Both tag edits and post edits hit the Suggested Edits queue, so then why is tag-edit reviewing not able to be seen? Is this a bug, or intentional?

<s>From what I understand, the issue isn't a one off, but, it'll try and reproduce it again.</s>

This isn't a one-off thing: first I edited [url-routing](/questions/tagged/url-routing) on Code Review, then, [binary-search](/questions/tagged/binary-search) just now and was presented with the same response.

The site this was tested on was [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ShadowWizard, the issue isn't one off, so linking to a specific tag would be pointless

Comment: Oh.... you are talking about **tag wiki edits**. Pretty sure it was already reported.

Comment: Well, if it's a bug then this report is the first. However if the bug is by design, there is already [feature request asking to change the behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255841/link-to-review-entry-in-header-after-suggesting-a-tag-wiki-edit)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be a feature-request because it's never happened before, so it's probably a dupe of @Sha's link...

Comment: Only devs can know if this is a bug or not. If code exists to show the link but does not work then it's a bug. If for whatever reason they never coded in a link then it's bydesign.

Comment: @James there are two different kinds of suggested edits: ordinary, where they did put a link, and tag wiki edits, where there is no link. Since the code is different, having it in one but missing from the other is right on the fine line between bug or by design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We don't know if the code is different or not. They could utilise the same class(es) to output that message passing in the specific text and expecting a link back. Or one of them be code from an older period not yet updated/refactored, etc etc. Can only speculate what code might be used :)

Comment: @James OK then, I *speculate* that {{read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263934/unable-to-view-tag-edit-review?noredirect=1#comment859075_263934}}