# How do I find a rejected suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit to a question but that revision was reject. Where can I find the particular suggested edit, or better yet the question itself? I would like to try and reword the question again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1788964/abhishek-asthana?tab=activity&sort=suggestions is a list of your suggestions. It will contain the rejected ones as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes and no. I was looking specifically for rejected suggestions.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. I was expecting rejected suggestions to be marked as rejected or something similar. Should that be a feature request?

Comment: Somewhere a suggestion like that rings a bell. That might already be around.

Comment: Damn!! One of these days I'll have an original suggestion.

Comment: @Bart I think you mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166992/152859)? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your [*activity* tab, filtered by *suggestions*, in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788964/abhishek-asthana?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). There you'll find all suggested edits you made:

[image: suggested edits]

The table links you to both the suggested edit page (with the review decision) and the post itself.

Comment: Thanks I found it. I was looking for rejected suggestion or something similar and that's why i couldn't find it earlier.