# Show the outcome of suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, profile-page

Here you see links to your suggested edits but you cannot find out, which are accepted and which were rejected and why:

https://askubuntu.com/users/34298/rubo77?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Please add the outcome (accepted/rejected) to the Activity->Suggestions page.

Comment: Closely related, might be dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166992/could-we-add-a-tab-for-rejected-edits

Comment: The outcome for each suggested edit is just one click away already. See [my answer to your support question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231011/246931) (but I would also find it useful to see the result on the activity page too).

Comment: I'm not sure when the change happened, but the outcome with a link to the queue is now available on your activity page.