# Suggested edit approved despite being rejected five times

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits

I would like an explanation for the aforementioned incident that happened on EL&U.

But before I begin, I tried looking for any possible duplicates using the search function; [is:question suggested edit review approved rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=4&tab=votes&q=is%3Aquestion%20suggested%20edit%20review%20approved%20rejected)  but simply gave up on the fourth page. So, I'm really sorry if my question has been asked before. (By the way, is there a way I can further narrow down the search?)

I'd like to know how a trivial edit, which was rejected five times consecutively, still managed to be approved and implemented.

[image]

the exact same edit was then approved by two users

[image]

The edit was not harmful, and the users who approved of the edit probably agreed that the period/full stop was misplaced. It seems obvious to me that the deletion of "now" was completely gratutious, and a means of overcoming the six characters limit. Fine, I'm not too bothered by that.

It's the statistics that puzzle me, **the suggested edit was rejected five times in a row**, and yet it still got approved. How come?

EDIT
I double-checked the SE rules concerning suggested edits

> In response to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted), we've bumped up the number of reviews required to approve or reject a suggested edit:
>
> - **Network-wide**: two reviews per edit suggestion.
> - **Stack Overflow**: three reviews per edit suggestion.
>
> Moderators can approve suggested edits instantly in cases where an insufficient number of users are available to review them.

Comment: @rene  Isn't the review queue, and the rules that govern whether suggested edits are approved or not, set by Stack Exchange? I'm not really concerned *why* some users approved this edit, I'm asking why wasn't the edit rejected after five users had clicked on the reject button. *That's* the difference.

Comment: The same edit was rejected only two times, not five times, then approved. It can be seen clearly [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/146982/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @ShadowWizard The screenshot says differently, I count five rejects, I don't understand.

Comment: Five reject actions. Each review takes 2 reject actions to be completed, so it means only 2 edits rejected

Comment: @ShadowWizard so if I were a low-rep user I could force-feed my edit as many times as necessary in order for it to be approved, as long as it happened on the one day. Is that it?

Comment: No, at some point you will be automatically banned for a week from suggesting new edits, it depends on the amount of accepted edits you had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [activity page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/146982/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9?tab=activity) of the user that suggested the edit it appears they have suggested an edit on it a total of three times, so you are seeing identical suggested edits submitted on three different occasions by the same person:

[image]

Comment: But the edit suggested was identical. How is it possible that the same user can  suggest the same edit three times?

Comment: Just start another edit once rejected. Maybe there should be some throttling or checking at the second edit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA why not? Only after 5 or 6 rejected edits the user is blocked from suggesting further edits for a week.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think there's any rule about that, you might for example try again if you think an edit was wrongly rejected. But of course at some point as Shadow Wizard mentioned you'll be blocked if enough are rejected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, wasn't his edit rejected five times?

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, like I explained in the comment on the queston those are just 5 reject *votes*. The formula for suggested edits ban is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337) - it's old, but still relevant to this day

Comment: The "so you are seeing different suggested edits" is a little misleading. It sounds as if the user has suggested three different edits, they are not, all three suggestions are identical. What happened is that the same user suggested a more substantial edit the previous day which was immediately approved, and then proposed the punctuation edit (maybe he had forgotten to include that tiny edit in the earlier one)  If you could clarify your statement, i.e. the user proposed the same edit three times, I'd be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, just edited, for some reason I got the second notification but not the first one.

Answer (score 11):

As [PeterJ correctly stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272463/245360), it was a second edit and a third edit. The last one eventually got approved.

I think we should help users to understand they shouldn't make the exact same edits over and over again if a first was rejected.

I think we should show a box or something pointing to the rejected review(s) once a user starts suggesting another edit on the post. A user can be warned such behavior could lead to trouble. (And this was [proposed already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184665/245360))

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184665/system-should-detect-new-users-mistakenly-making-repeated-same-or-similar-edit

Comment: Meh, why you always ruin my excellent 'new' ideas ;) @Sha

Comment: Nah, leave it be - it kind of completes Peter's answer. My pleasure ruining your "new" ideas! :D

Comment: No, don't delete. I like the suggestion.

Comment: Now poor @Mari can't decide which answer to accept... ;)

Comment: Presumably the reviewers of the three attempted edits were different people.  I would hope that someone seeing ostensibly the same edit appearing twice in the review queue would look into why.

Comment: @Chenmunka nope. Two users reviewed twice, and changed their minds each time. See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158809) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158817), Ricky and macraf.

Comment: Hmm.  Then I see another opportunity for improvement - but very difficult to implement and irrelevant if the suggestion in this answer is implemented.

Comment: @Chenmunka only thing we might be able to do here is ask those users directly why they approved/changed their minds, but personally think it's just a waste of time over such a minor thing.