# Edit rejection should be clearly indicated for the first few occasions, with notifications

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications

This is related to [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

...but my feature request is hopefully less contentious.

I am a new user (I joined last year, but just did one post then, I think, and just started up again now), so I speak from recent experience when I say that **feedback on suggested edits is lacking**.

I suggested multiple edits that were rejected for the same reason, and that happened only because I did not have a chance to learn the reason for the first rejection before I made the other, similar requests.  The only reason I even know the reason now is because I decided to comb through all areas of my profile page.

Having loud and clear notifications for edit rejections across the board, which was discussed in the question linked to above, divided people, so I propose a more minor change:

I suggest **clear notifications be provided for any user's *first few edits (or at least the first one) rejected***.  Of course, since users would not be able to count on those notifications showing up indefinitely, the notification should also clearly mention that such notifications will eventually stop.

Comment: I'd also say that for the first few (rejected) suggested edits, that a specific reason why the edit was rejected, linking to specific parts of the edit that didn't meet edit requirements, should be given.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy No as the reason is usually clear and also due to the problem with roboreviewers before you could write a reason the edit would be approved.

Comment: @Mark, since we are talking about new editors' first few edits, I don't think you can really state that the reason is "usually clear".  Now, if your point about roboreviewers (which I don't quite understand) is true, and putting the reason in the notification **can't** be implemented, then a good middle ground might be just including a link to *where* a person can find out the reason.  Of course, a rejection notification alone will be enough in most cases, since curiosity ("Rejected? Why??") should take over.