# Is there a way to link to the results of a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

If a suggested edit is rejected by peer review, is there a way to view a page with the results of the peer voting on that specific edit suggestion?

This can be done while the edit suggestion is still pending (or after it is accepted), but I can't find any evidence of the voting record after the suggested edit is rejected.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions shows your suggestions -  replace `current` with `users/{user-id}` to get to the suggestion tab of someone else. Pick an edit you want.

Comment: @nicael: That is for suggested edits I have made (I haven't made any - my rep is too high). I suppose I could have opened the page for the user who made the suggested it before it was rejected - but after the edit is rejected there seems to be no way to get there given just the question page.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a legit point. Then, if the post was created more than a week ago, you can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/127462/all-suggested-edits-on-a-post). But if it's new, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the suggested edits on that post, except of becoming a mod :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184670/edit-rejection-should-be-clearly-indicated-for-the-first-few-occasions-with-not

Comment: If only the timeline was to become official, it was a perfect fit for this, however as it's not official and actually might vanish any day, I can't see any proper place to have those details. Revisions list doesn't sound right since rejected edits do not affect the post. Adding special link also sounds too "intrusive".

Comment: This is something that is lacking, but if you visited the review, it should appear in your browser history

Comment: @psubsee2003: Normally the edit review pops up in a window that doesn't have its own URL, so it does not appear in the browser history.

Comment: @GregHewgill of course, forgot about that.  When you encounter it via review, then you can see it but obviously not relevant in your case..  If you accepted or rejected it does it show up in the "reviews" tab of your profile then?

Comment: @psubsee2003: Ah, the "reviews" tab. There it is. Would you add that as an answer to this question please?

Comment: @GregHewgill I tried to cover all of the options in the answer, but the reviews tab is in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General speaking, there are 4 ways to access the suggested edit review results, but one of which has a significant rep requirement and requires a lot of searching (especially on busy sites).

- If you encountered the suggested edit via the review queue, you will see it in your browser history.  If you found the suggested edit directly in the post by clicking the `edit(1)` link, then this option won't work for you.
- If you have 20K rep, you can see **every** review via the `/review/<queue>/history` page.  This will have a record of every single review (so it could take a lot of searching for a busy site).  If you have less than 20K, it will just have your reviews.  However, if you are looking for an edit you reviewed, it should be there.
- If you know the user that suggested the edit, you can visit their own suggestions via `/users/<user id>?tab=activity&sort=suggestions`
- And if all else fails and you performed a review of the edit, it will be in your own reviews tab: `/users/<user id>?tab=activity&sort=reviews`

However, a direct link to reject edits to a specific post would be useful if it can be put in a non-obtrusive place (the timeline as @ShawdowWizard would be great, if the page would become official and linked, which is unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

With the [revamped timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/986753), one can access the review of a rejected suggested edit by clicking on the clock icon below the vote icons; this will take you to the timeline for that post, where an entry for the completed review of the suggested edit will appear. (Of course, plenty of other information is also accessible on the timeline, not just the rejected suggested edits.)