# Reviews: Handling invalid -yet good to be added as comment- edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, review, suggested-edits

## The problem

I come across a lot of edits where people trying to point out something to the OP. Sometimes it contains useful information that would benefit everyone reading it. Still it is invalid because it radically change the post / modify the code. Mostly they come from new users but what triggered me to start this is that I found similar edits coming from users with 1k+ rep.

## Example

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2395201); the user modified the code and added this warning:

> be careful, in case `NAME` is `NULL`, then `anything + NULL` will generate `NULL`

## Suggestion:

Add reject reason: **Rejected because it is a comment**. This will send the users a notification with a link to redirect them to the post with their edit/comment entered in the comments box to review and post it correctly.

## Other examples:

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2411736)

Comment: Rejecting it as "invalid edit: This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." seems to work?

Comment: Yes but I am asking how to notify their owners about the rejection and maybe redirect them to the post with their edit entered in the comments box for example?

Comment: You can't, other than the flag which they'll see if they go into their suggestions-history in their profile. Are you suggesting a feature?

Comment: Yes I am suggesting if that could be a new feature. Will retag the post

Comment: Cool. Sorry if I sound terse and abrupt - I haven't had my coffee yet. ;)

Comment: Can you explain your feature request?  What exactly are you proposing?  That editors be notified of all rejected edits?  Or just specific ones that meet certain criteria?  If it is the latter, what is the trigger or criteria for notifying the editor?

Comment: I updated the question and explained things better

Comment: @AhmadAlfy interesting idea.  `Rejected because it is a comment` probably overlaps with `Invalid Edit` now, so that would either need to be removed or changed.  Also, there have been numerous requests in various forms to display notifications to editors on rejected edits, but have not been well supported by the SE team - specifically Jeff (despite community support).  Here the [reasoning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/123439#123439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owners already get notifications about any edits to their post -- both suggested edits and normal edits. The notification persists even if the suggested edit is approved:

[image]

This ought to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but I never got such notification. Where is that?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Noifications section. Right next to your inbox.