# My edit disappeared without any reason provided

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Within the last hour or so, I made suggested edits to a question ("[Why does greyscale work the way it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311774/why-does-greyscale-work-the-way-it-does)") to fix minor grammar errors.  I explained that the edits were minor, but that the question ranked in the first five in the Google results returned for the "grayscale algorithm" search phrase, and therefore I wanted to further improve it.

After submitting my edits, I received the usual "your edits will need to be reviewed" message.  But after waiting for more than 10 minutes, my edits simply disappeared upon page refresh.  There was no "rejected" notice, or any other notice for that matter.

Why is this?  Is this a fluke, or what really happened?

Comment: Good question, and thanks for being a conscientious enough editor to care and follow up. That bodes well for you in the future. You might also be interested in supporting this popular feature request: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Comment: +1 @CodyGray: Thank you for your comment.  I have upvoted the feature request you reference in your comment.  For once, I don't agree w/ Jeff Atwood's position that informing the user about a rejection would be a slap-in-the-face. "Silent rejections" are more of a slap-in-the-face, in my opinion. PS: I am going to try undercurrent soon as I have time.  Thought I was the only one who hated the search box animation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your edit was rejected by 3 users as too minor.  It was approved by two users who reviewed it, but was rejected overall.

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2554641

[image]

There is no notice given when edits are rejected, you have to check in the Activity tab on your profile.

[image]

Comment: +1 Is there a mechanism to contest the decisions?  Thanks.

Comment: You could always repropose it, but you'd probably end up with the same result.  Remember, editing a question bumps it to the front page, so substantial edits are preferred.

Comment: I think "weighting" was correct there, and the other edits didn't really change much beyond minor grammar, the meaning was all there.

Comment: Thank you jonsca, although there is reputation gain from editing, I really do it to improve stackoverflow, and to give back.  Rejects have the negative effect of discouraging users like myself.  In addition to being a software engineer, I am also a professional translator. PS: Waiting on the time limit to accept your answer.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, minor edits are not encouraged.  I wouldn't sweat it, get right back on the horse and find some posts that really need help.

Comment: > "get right back on the horse" -- now that actually made me smile, thank you!