# Allow rejected editors to be @replied to

Tags: feature-request, comments, suggested-edits, comment-replies, rejected-edits

Within the canonical answer on [how-do-comment-replies-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) it is clear that post editors can be replied to.

> Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties,
>   commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and **editors
>   of the question or answer that you are commenting on**—users not in that
>   list cannot be notified. You can also notify a ♦ moderator who closed
>   the question. The question and answers are all considered
>   independently. For example, if Alice was the author of, commented on,
>   or edited the question or her answer, then you cannot notify her by
>   commenting on Bob's answer (unless Alice also participated in that
>   answer), and vice versa.

However, thanks to [this comment by Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to#comment631364_198977), it has become clear that this only applies to *approved* editors (in addition to binding editors). I wish to request that comment replies be extended to include any user who suggested a *rejected* edit on the post.

**Background**
The reason I would wish to reply to a rejected editor would be if their edit, while inappropriate, hinted at important information; for example that the answer was wrong or incomplete. In those cases I may wish to encourage them to outline this in a comment or competing answer.

Comment: As far as I know, only user who actually made an edit can be replied-to so "rejected editor" can't be reached. The only option currently is to comment on one of his posts or reply to one of his comments. I do it sometimes and delete the comment after a short while so it won't make noise.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This should be an answer.

Comment: @hims056 I think this better be changed to feature request asking to add any user who *suggested* an edit to the list of reply-to users so my comment isn't really an answer. Also, knowing this site for years I *might* be wrong. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I thought as much but I didn't want to presume. I shall now convert to a feature request (For the record had you of provided an answer I would have created a new post as a feature request to avoid invalidating your answer)

Comment: @RichardTingle cheers, I fully support your request. ;)

Comment: I think the best option is to use a custom reject message. Ok, no notification, but THAT could be changed.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn While I think I agree, that was (sort of) rejected way back; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/123439#123439 as it was to notify a user of something they could do nothing about. On the other hand a comment saying "don't do x, why not do y" is something they very much can do something about

Comment: Well, what you now suggest would lead to exact that "You've done something wrong." kind of message.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn We equally can't stop people swearing at each other, but this at least has a decent chance of having good comments going through it