# How do I flag an editor?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I know [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011329/yuvi?tab=activity) is actually trying to be helpful by formatting code, but it appears that the first line of code is always indented incorrectly (maybe it's just my OCD). After about three of their edited posts corrections, which somehow always got approved, I ended up going through just the first page of approved edits this user made, and corrected the same problem.

- I don't think it would be correct to add a comment directed at the editor asking them to correct this issue.
- I don't see any way to flag a user for moderator review, or have the moderator contact them.
- I don't see a method to flag an edit for review.
- and I don't see any other way to contact this user to help them correct the problem and save a lot of people extra work.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Why do you not see it as appropriate to comment to them? If people are making honest mistakes then reaching out to them is all that’s usually necessary

Comment: The comment isn't really related and detracts from the question

Comment: I stopped doing suggested edits but I still come across wrongly approved ones from time to time, I just use a custom flag on one of the edited posts to bring it to the moderator's their attention. The amount of invalid edits being approved by new reviewers is so high it's just demotivating.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to flag `vi` as very low quality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you think someone is 'with good intention' making a mistake then there is absolutely no reason not to contact them and politely mention it. The post that they most recently (successfully) edited seems an appropriate place for this. They may even thank you for resolving their misunderstanding.

This can be done by [@TheirName notifying them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). This can be used to contact anyone in the revision history so successful editors can be contacted, [failed editors cannot.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to)

Flags should only be used to deal with problems you cannot deal with yourself. In this case it can easily be dealt with by any member since there is no malice here only mistake.

Once the issue is resolved comments can be deleted if you wish to clean up the comment chain on the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks... no harm in trying.

Comment: @Mottie If you're worried about the question OP getting pinged unnessissarily then be aware that when you edit the question to fix the problem it pings them anyway. 2 pings to a question is much the same as 1

Comment: @Richard if the edit is small enough (less than X character changed, body only) it won't send the post author any notification. :)

Comment: I was just about to ask how can I be sure they get a notification when their name only appears on the editor page.

Comment: @Mottie Anyone in the revision history can be contacted, so a successful editor can be contacted. A failed editor cannot

Comment: Ok thanks... I posted a comment. Lets see if it works!

Comment: @Mottie: indeed that's true, though the autocomplete does not appear to function in that case.

Comment: It looks like he replied positively... so success! This time :)

Answer (score 4):

You can leave a comment on a post with an `@mention` of any editor (whether the edit was an approved suggested edit or a direct edit). The editor's name won't be autocompleted, but the editor will be notified.

This is suboptimal, because it is irrelevant to the author of the post and to other readers. But if you see a case where a user is making many edits of the same kind, leave one comment to tell him what he's doing wrong. Just one, no more, and come back a couple of days later to delete it.

The ideal way to contact an editor is in chat. But that only works if the user does participate in chat. There's no easy way to locate a user's chat account, all you can do is [look up the user name](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users) and verify that it's the same user and not a homonym.

If you see a repeated pattern of misbehavior, flag any post for moderator attention. This only applies to actual misbehavior, such as a prolific editor who repeatedly makes posts worse. I don't think this case quite qualifies but I didn't delve in deeply. But try commenting first. Flagging should be reserved for egregious cases, involving malicious or at least highly careless behavior.