# Can we contact the author of a rejected edit?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I just saw a user who has [repeatedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26091) [tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26090) to [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26079) a question on Meta. Judging by the edit comments, the user seems to be mistaken about the nature of Meta Stack Overflow.

I would like to point this out to the user, but this user has no posts on any Stack Exchange sites; this user's reputation comes strictly from suggested edits.

Can we @-comment the submitter of a rejected edit? It would be helpful in showing editors how the system works.

Comment: That user is probably a bot, currently attempts are being made in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) to reach a CM.

Comment: Sadly only successful editors can be replied to. But there is a proposal requesting that this be added; [Allow failed editors be @replied to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to)

Comment: What amuses me the most is how quite a few of the bot's suggested edits are being approved...

Comment: @RichardTingle Ok, that makes my question a duplicate. Voted to close mine as dupe - and upvoted that one.

Comment: Not a single post in 50 accounts and only gibberish in the about me section so no, no way to contact. But being a spam bot, no point contacting it anyway.

Comment: It's a crap bot... all it's doing is removing tags - though it looks like some have been approved.

Comment: @ben in the past it used to deface posts, see [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5444)

Comment: It's really a bizarre thing to do. Even the edit comment doesn't contain any spam

Comment: It might be in training. To see if it works, flies under the radar, before replacing the innocuous content with more offensive and harmful material.

Comment: Usually spammers don't go out of their way to earn rep... so it may be specifically targeting Stack Exchange sites.