# Suggested edits accepted/declined history or graph

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Is there a place or an option to see my own suggested edits with their review status (accepted or declined) in form of a list or a graph?

I'd like it to be more like a list of my flags where there is a visible thing that says **[active]** or the reason why it was declined. It'd make it much easier to see if and where I have gone wrong.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/136479#136479 has dozens of linked posts that are related.

Comment: There's tons of requests to add more info to the suggested edit page in your profile. The one I linked to suggests to add the status right there, which is what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the last paragraph of the question and the screenshot that goes with it.

Comment: Alright, now I see it. I guess it's a duplicate then.

Comment: [Here is a query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-on-users#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&ids=1306322&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) that does it too.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, there is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306322/user1306322?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: But it doesn't show if they were accepted or declined. Just a list of them.

Comment: @user1306322 You can click the link to see the suggestion itself, which indicates whether it's approved or not.

Comment: I'd like it to be more like a list of my flags where there is a visible thing that says **[active]** or the reason why it was declined. It'd make it much easier to see if and where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @user1306322 There is no such page for that.  You could potentially create a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for it though.

Comment: I'm very bad at queries :<