# New Achievement notification is not eye catching

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications, top-bar

When we get new achievement (Eg: Badge) There will be small color change to achievements button on title bar of SE sites. But it is not getting caught easily. Usually I came to know about achievement of new badges from no of badge count from title bar. It will be nice to have more visible alert (Just like reputation change notification) for this.

[image]

Comment: I dunno, maybe my peripheral vision is enhanced by too many video games, but it seems plenty eye catching to me. How much of a distraction *should* a badge really be?

Comment: Maybe a slightly brighter shade of green would work? But I think it's fine as is - I wouldn't want some random badge to distract me too much

Comment: One possible issue is colorblindness, which often affects perception of green...but I'm not sure that this wouldn't just be perceived as a different color in that case, and still equally eye-catching. FWIW, it took me a while to figure out why it's sometimes colored, and I do feel a slight need to pay extra attention to it when I'm expecting a badge. I.e., I don't expect to notice it out of the corner of my eye, like I would with comments or rep gains. It's definitely not THAT eye-catching.

Comment: On the contrary; [turn the whole thing down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210637/on-rep-changes-highlight-icon-in-top-bar-instead-of-showing-number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to color blindness of my eye as all others can distinguish it easily...