# Why was I warned to edit constructively?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, system-message

When trying to edit a post on security.stackexchange.com I saw the following screen:

[image: (no description)]

Why is that?

Comment: That's not a warning. It's just a guideline.

Comment: I never saw it before.

Comment: It's a ***GIANT BOLD RED*** guideline. Don't make a mistake and you'll live. Have a nice day!

Comment: IS Exchange takes themselves very seriously.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a warning; just a reminder.

There has been [some discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/248072) of showing warnings, but this isn't that

The colors on security.se seem to be pretty bold, making it look like a warning. It's really just the same color as the side "How to Edit" section. Observe the equivalent message here on meta.se:

> [image]

---

To see the status of your past suggested edits, go to your profile and select the **Activity** tab, then **Suggestions**. For your account on security.se, that link would be:

https://security.stackexchange.com/users/15648/d33tah?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Because you still don't have the ["Edit Questions And Answers" privilege](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) which requires 2000 reputation points on the site.

You can always edit your own posts regardless of reputation, but to edit other user's post you need to have enough reputation points. Until you have that privilege, your edit will be reviewed by other users who should confirm it's a valid and good edit.

Full details are available here: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)