# Input required on a rejected edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, too-minor

Was it correct to reject [this edit suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30940)? If yes then what would have been an appropriate reject reason? Closest would be "Invalid edit" which states, "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post" but the edit under question is not an attempt to reply. Asking this question in light of [What should be used in place of "Too Minor?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor).

Comment: It occurs to me that the edit might have been made intentionally as an attempt to prove that "too minor" shouldn't have been removed. Much the same way that some people comment with stuff like "asdfdfhgjkshdflh" to prove a point when people raise the topic of requiring comments on downvotes.

Comment: @JonK good point, didn't think of it from that perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too minor. It's adding something to the post, however something that is not correct in my opinion, hence my rejection.

The word "halp" is common enough to understand it's an intentional typo of "help".