# Send a notification if @name is used in an edit suggestion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, notifications

I just now noticed that when someone refers to another person using `@name` in an edit suggestion, the other person (me in this case) does **not** get a notification.

I only saw this situation as I clicked on my approved edit and was curious what the next edit was.
However, clearly someone was trying to give me advice, which in different circumstances would have never reached me.

Can notifications of such sort be implemented?

Picture for reference:

> [image: @name usage in suggested edits]

Comment: If I remember right, the person who made the subsequent correction can leave you a comment in the @name format and it would ping you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Revision edit summaries are not for pinging other users or having conversations - they're for explaining why you made an edit. That's the only way they should be used, and the only way we want to encourage they be used.

Any user can ping any other user who has edited the question via the comments, and that is the preferred method of contacting someone who made an edit they shouldn't have made.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is particularly useful. There are just a few places that allow comments and pings. If you would allow pinging users from the revision history, you need a way to flag them, review them, etc. That seems an awful lot of work for something not very frequently used. A comment on the post is the most appropriate since it is A) visible, and B) uses existing flows for flagging, etc.

I do agree on the (possible duplicate) [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor), which states that there should be feedback about the reviewing process. I just don't think your proposal is the best solution for this.