# Add notifications about accepted edit suggestions

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, notifications, global-inbox

Consider a new SO user with insufficient reputation to make an edit with no approval.

When such users suggest an edit, they can hardly guess that it is possible to keep track of their edit, discover if it is either approved or rejected, and that there may be a comment that describes a reason of the rejection that can help avoid the same situation in future.

The issue is that this tracking information is hidden deep inside a user profile. You need to follow *User Page* → *All Actions* → *Suggestions (possibly)*. There is a little chance that an average newcomer even knows what “suggestions” is for, even if they are curious enough to dig into every tab of their own profile.

**So I propose** to add a notification in the *Recent inbox messages* area when a suggested edit is either accepted or declined. The notification entry must lead to a review page of a corresponding edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Users are already notified of both of these situations.

- When their edit is approved, they gain reputation for it (2) which will appear in their achievements dialog and reputation history. If they were rep capped, it still appears but just doesn't trigger a rep increase notification.
- When their edit is rejected, they'll [see a message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334) which links them *directly* to that suggested edit the next time they attempt to suggest an edit. If they continue getting rejections, they'll get linked to the list of their recent suggestions so they can review them.

Comment: Can\`t tell about post edits (I passed a reputational border for immediate editing). But I checked the same for tag description editing right now, and there was no notification in the inbox on rejection of my edit (I asked a high rep user to help me with testing). Do I need address this issue to Ru.SO community manager or this issue really has place across SE?

Comment: @Arhad We don't send *inbox* notifications. The notification appears *on the edit page* when attempting to suggest another edit.

Comment: It is clear for me now, thanks. I proposed *inbox notifications* because it looks (for me) more notable way to get a feedback if an edit was ineffectual for some reason. I mean, there is a bright button on always visible panel (at least the panel is presented on each page and allows to get notifications ASAP) and no necessarity to begin a new editing.