# Rejected edit banner is too easily overlooked

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Ordinarily, when you go to suggest an edit, you see this banner:

1. > [image: Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed. / We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.]

When your last edit was rejected, you see something like this:

2. > [image: Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed. / Attention! Your last edit was rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review the reasons given for rejecting it before continuing.]

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/323179) there's two other messages that are shown to users closer to being banned. I don't have pictures (because I'm not a bad editor), but I assume that they both start with "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed", and have second paragraphs that look like this:

3. > Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review your [recently-rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before continuing.

4. > **Warning!** Some of your previous edits were rejected. Please review your [recently-rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before continuing. Too many rejected edits may cause your editing privileges to be suspended.

---

The first time you suggest an edit, you might read banner #1. After that, why would you bother to read it again? It's not like the content *looks* like it will change. It doesn't really matter that there is a link where there wasn't one before (banners #2, 3, 4), or **bold formatting** (banner #4). It just isn't noticeable enough.

Until recently, I don't think I had any idea that there were any banners other than #1 (plus a similar one shown to anonymous editors), and I've suggested a lot of edits, and inevitably had some rejected. I'm sure that I'm [not the only one to not notice it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324111/6083675).

There should be something to differentiate banners #2, 3, and 4 from banner #1. I'm thinking an icon could work, or a change in color. But *something* needs to change.