# Notify on suggested edit rejection

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Whenever an edit I suggest gets rejected, I don't know unless I get curious and check the page. Is there any way that a notification can be sent out when they are rejected, similar to when badges are earned or when privileges are gained?

Comment: @Matt: Oops, didn't see that when I searched

Comment: I support this 100%.

Comment: I would like to be notified of these [cowboy rejects](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113727/how-can-i-appeal-a-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit) as well.