# Links are not parsed in preview, but are parsed after editing

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

Here's the [question body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176365/how-can-mistakenly-reject-edits-be-reverted-and-the-reviewers-notified).

The links after the paragraph after the numbered list, aren't parsed in the preview. If you remove the paragraph right after the numbered list, they *are* parsed.

[image]

Comment: is there space between [] and () ? to me its looks there is space between [] and () http://i.stack.imgur.com/L5LoC.png

Comment: @NullPonyPointer Go look at the question (and for best experience copy the source into a new question to see the broken preview), there's no space.  No wacky invisible characters in that paragraph that makes the difference between proper rendering and not either.  *Weird.*

Comment: I can't quite imagine who would downvote this question, but someone did. Please explain, is there anything I can do to improve this bug report?

Comment: @NullPonyPointer: if there were a space, then the links would not be rendered *at all*, neither in the preview, nor after posting the edit. And nor would they be parsed if I removed the paragraph after the numbered list.